# Double ```for``` loop

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a nesting `for` loop to calculate points for my cribbage game. Right now I'm trying to figure out a method for counting all the '15's in the players `hand`. The way I currently have the system set up makes it so if `'dT'` is in the `hand`, the card art for the ten of diamonds will print.

What I currently have (that is related to this question) is

```
hand = [] # this is filled by the rest of the program
handCombos = []

def count15s():
    for _ in range(6):
      possiblePairs = {'T5','J5','Q5','K5','78','96','5T','5J','5Q','5K','87','69'}

      first = hand[0][1] 
      second = hand[2][1]
      
      combo = ''.join(first+second)
      if(combo in possiblePairs):
         print('ham')     # placeholder so the program can run without an error

      print(combo)
```

This works for what it is supposed to--if the second part of the first term + the second part of the third term is in the list of possible pairs, then it prints 'ham' to the console. The problem with this, however, is that 1) It prints 'ham' 6 times, and 2) It actually does what it's supposed to.

I'm looking for a way that I can nest a `for` loop inside another one so it can scan every combination of '15's in the `hand`, then that specific combination to the `handCombos` array so that it can't be used again. I know that I need a `for` loop somewhere but the way I'm thinking of doing it would end up with a triple loop and I don't think that this is the best way to do it.

Comment: Use `itertools.combinations()`.

Comment: Why are you using a loop right now? It performs the same operation on the hand list 6 times, explaining why it is printing 'ham' 6 times. It's also not very clear to me what I should understand under '15'? Is this some sort of card combination?

Comment: @Barmar do you have a good website that explains how to use that?

Comment: @lcdumort It helps to know the card game cribbage. You get points for each subset of cards in your hand whose values add up to 15 (royals are all worth 10).